# Can't add ppa behind proxy?

Tags: 14.04, apt, ppa, proxy, gnupg

First I set up `/etc/apt/apt.conf` to use my proxy and now I can update with `sudo apt-get update`. Now I want to add some ppas but can't.

I try to add a PPA behind my proxy so I set up `http_proxy` and `https_proxy`

```
export http_proxy=......
export https_proxy=.....
```

then I do

```
$ sudo -E add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpf97t7hiy/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpf97t7hiy/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key 8844C542 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpgkeys: key 165D673674A995B3E64BF0CF4F191A5A8844C542 can't be retrieved
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

So then I try to add it manually:

```
$ sudo -E apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 8844C542
Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --homedir /tmp/tmp.4ESVuO8uFh --no-auto-check-trustdb --trust-model always --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 8844C542
gpg: requesting key 8844C542 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpgkeys: key 8844C542 can't be retrieved
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

Nothing I try works. Help.

Edit: Figured it out....The keyserver just wasn't working apparently keyserver.ubuntu.com is down permanently......Had to use:

```
sudo -E apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://subkeys.pgp.net --recv-keys C2518248EEA14886
```

Edit: It isn't a duplicate question....keyserver.ubuntu.com was down for me and had to user a different one. The other guys got it working with the default keyserver and only had to add their proxy. I had to add my proxy, plus manually add the gpg keys using a different key server.

Comment: That guy got it working, I did everything it said in there and it's still not working...So my guess is the bug pointed out there isn't the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a list of alt servers that can be used -

keyserver hkp://subkeys.pgp.net
keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu
keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net (random server)
keyserver hkp://keys.nayr.net
keyserver http://keys.gnupg.net
keyserver http://wwwkeys.xx.pgp.net where xx is a two-letter country code.